# Can OpenClover work along with JDO enhancment?

Tags: jdo, instrumentation, test-coverage, clover

We have a gradle project that uses [jdo enhancement](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ref_guide_pc_enhance.html). Basically:

> The enhancer post-processes the bytecode generated by your Java compiler, adding the necessary fields and methods to implement the required persistence features.

When I try to add test coverage using the [open clover plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-clover-plugin) - my tests begin to fail. This is because OpenClover uses [source code instrumentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/clover/why-does-clover-use-source-code-instrumentation-79986998.html).

OpenClover moved the 'jdo-enhanced' classes as a backup - and built its own instrumented version of the classes, therefore losing all the jdo-enhancements.

Given this quandary, is it possible to use openClover (source code instrumentation) and jdo enhancement together? Is it even theoretically possible?

Comment: why can you not "JDO enhance" the compiled classes, then run the Clover enhancement after that?

Comment: so as far as I understand, clover is adding its 'instrumentation' code in .java files and then compiling them. so if I run clover even after jdo enhancement, it goes back to .java and disregards bytcode directly modified by the enhancer.

Comment: I actually misunderstood jdo-enhancement a little bit, it post-processes the "bytecode" and not the "source". So I guess I can try running jdo-enhancement after clover and see what happens (if it will jdo-enhance the clover-instrumented classes).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike clover instrumentation, JDO-enhancement modifies the bytecode, and not the source.
Therefore these tasks *can* be serialized. 
`cloverInstrumentation -> compileCloverJava -> runJDOEnhancer`

Assuming you have a method runJdoEnhancer that takes in the sourceSet as input, this should work:

`compileCloverJava.doLast {
    runJdoEnhancer(sourceSets.clover, configurations.cloverRuntime)
}`